# What is an 'S-factor' in nuclear physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, astrophysics, nuclear-physics

I have seen the "S-factor" in many places, but I've never read an explanation of what it actually is. I have read that it is related to the cross-section of a reaction, but that's about it.

Comment: Can you link to an example of the context? (Also, where did you look to try to figure this out yourself?)

Comment: Can't it be that you make a confusion with the S-matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S-factor separates out the Coulomb interaction (barrier) energy term from the cross-section $\sigma$, e.g.,

$$ 
\sigma(E) = E^{-1} e^{-2\pi\eta} S(E)
$$
where $\eta$ is a dimensionless factor relating to the Coulomb barrier.

It can be useful for finding a small resonance within a large electric field (image from [here](http://www.jinaweb.org/docs/Nuclear_Astrophysics_II.pdf)):
[image: Diagram of S-factor]

Comment: What's that grey tail at the left-hand side of the S-factor vs. energy graph?

Comment: Also, after reading a few articles online, I have seen that most people write it as $\sigma (E) = S(E) E^{-1}e^{-2\pi \eta}$. What do you have to say about that?

Comment: My error, that is the correct form - will edit.

Comment: Thanks. Also, a quick question - a resonance and the Gamow Window are unrelated, right? (I think you can tell why I'm asking)

Comment: I could open a new question for that if it would be more fitting.

Comment: The Gamow window is a more synoptic way of looking at reaction rates, it's sort of related to resonance but not in a huge way. You can read more about it [here](http://csep10.phys.utk.edu/astr162/lect/energy/temp-press.html).

Comment: Thank you! I also found a nice page on resonances at http://www.phy.duke.edu/~kolena/modern/dudley.html.